# How to fetch SQL info from UITableViewCell an use as credentials for MYSQL parsing

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, sqlite

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLBuA.jpg
[image]

If you take a look at the picture I provided, on the left hand side there is a table. This table loads SQLite data. The SQLite data has some data retrieved from a MYSQL database. The SQLite data is the following columns:

StoreID, StoreName, StoreAddr, StoreHost, StorePort, StoreUser, StorePass, StoreDB.

What's showing up in the table cell is clearly the StoreName and StoreAddr

On the right hand side of my picture, you can see some code that is implemented for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. The selection of a cell causes a segue to a view controller that calls MYSQL data specific to the SQLite credentials from the cell. For example, if I clicked Latin Bites Peruvian Cuisine, it should use the SQLite credentials to log into MYSQL and then parse the information back to 'detailedviewcontroller'

My question is: How do I have the 'Latin Bites' cell grab SQLite info (host, pass, db) to be used as MYSQL credentials? 

I can't target each individual cell's data. If there was just one entry in SQLite, then I would do a code similar to this:

```
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &companyDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
    [arrayOfStore removeAllObjects];

    NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM storelist"];
    const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare(companyDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {


            // Statement 1,2,3 etc. relates to the SQLite table in order.

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            NSString *address = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSString *host = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            NSString *pass = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
            NSString *db = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];





            NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                  dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                                  timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];



            NSString *salesStr = @"http://";
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:host];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@":8080/sales.php?password="];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:pass];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&db="];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:db];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&edate="];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:dateString];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&sdate="];
            salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:dateString];



NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:salesStr];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];



json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


NSLog(@"response type is %@",[json class]);

//Set up our cities array



storesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++)



            {


                NSString * netSales = json[@"netSales"];
                NSString * voids = json[@"voidSales"];
                NSString * discounts = json[@"discountSales"];
                NSString * guestCount = json[@"guestCount"];
                NSString * peopleServed = json[@"servedCount"];
                NSString * employeesClock = json[@"loggedIn"];



            Store * myStore = [[Store alloc]initWithNetSales: (NSString *) netSales andVoids: (NSString *) voids andDiscounts: (NSString *) discounts andGuestCount: (NSString *) guestCount andPeopleServed: (NSString *) peopleServed andEmployeesClock: (NSString *) employeesClock];




   [storesArray addObject:myStore];
```

But I need to have each individual cell pull it's SQLite data to be used as MYSQL credentials. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

Add a new private property...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Store *currentStore;
```

...to replace the local variable in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Set that in the same location in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, using the following...

```
[self setCurrentStore:[storesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Then add a `prepareForSegue` method to manage the setting of your `DetailViewController` properties, using an instance of `destinationViewController`.

```
ViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];
```

...and for example...

```
destinationVC.totalSales = self.currentStore.netSales;
```

---

**UPDATE**

In regards to your "disappearing?" comment on the correct location for your call to MySQL database, I note the following.

You are on the right track with placing this in your `prepareForSegue` method.

When using a Core Data managed SQLite db, I make an `NSFetchRequest` to my `NSManagedObjectContext` for either the object, or its `objectID`, as represented by the selected cell (in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`). I suspect this is the place to make your call to your MySQL db.

The subsequent segue animation helps cover any delay in obtaining returned values, not that this has ever been a problem for me with Core Data managed SQLite db.

Some considerations however...

What if your call to your MySQL db takes longer than the segue animation?

You cannot present your user with a blank `DetailViewController`.

You need a completion block for your call to your MySQL db.

You also need to alert the user to this process of obtaining external data, so think about presenting a UIAlertView with a simple message, and activating the network activity indicator.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

In your `DetailViewController` class, write a new method to display a `UIAlertView` .

So the process from within the `prepareForSegue` method...

1. Call that `UIAlertView` method using an instance of `destinationViewController`, so that it is displayed when the user arrives at the `DetailViewController`.
2. Activate the network activity indicator.
3. Make your call to the MySQL db.
4. Within the MySQL completion block, dismiss the `UIAlertView` and network activity indicator.
5. Within the MySQL completion block, load the downloaded data into your `DetailViewController`.

When the user arrives at the `DetailViewController` view, they witness an alert, the network activity indicator, then the downloaded MySQL data populated into the view.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Appreciate all of the info. This worked well